# Why constructor is not invoked after creating Object of the class?

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class A {                                    
    void A()  {
        System.out.println("Class A"); 
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args)  { 
        new A(); 
    } 
}
```

After running this program output is nothing means after `new A();`  `void A(){}` is not invoked.

`void A(){}` isn't a constructor ?

Comment: remove void from the name

Answer (score 2):

`void A()` is a regular method, not a constructor.

`A()` (without a return type) is a constructor.

```
A() 
{
    System.out.println("Class A"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write constructor in your class you wrote an ordinary method yet the compiler provides you a default constructor (constructor with no parameters) [read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)

To create constructor:-

1. Constructor name must be same as its class name
2. Constructor must have no explicit return type

ex:-

```
A() 
{
  System.out.println("Class A");    
}
```